# back pressing closes app even though keyboard is open

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have a searchView view in my activity. When i click on it, the keyboard opens (as it should) but when I press the back button I want it to close the keyboard (which is visible) but it closes the whole app. this started to happen after I added this code. This helps me to hide the keyboard when I touch outside of the keyboard:

```
    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (currentFocus != null) {
            val imm = this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }
```

What can I do so that pressing the back button first closes the open keyboard and only after that closes the app?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that code snipped is causing the described behavior? I just wrote a small sample app to replicate the issue. However, even with your `dispatchTouchEvent` code, the first back button press just closes the keyboard and only the second one exits the app.

I tested it with an emulator on API 30.

Have you per change also overwritten `onBackPressed()` and/or `onKeyDown()`?

**Edit:**

I think I've found the problem and why it was working for me, but not for you.

- First difference: You are using gesture navigation. If you switch to the 3-button navigation, I bet it will work for you, too.
- Second difference (likely): When using `SearchView`, I could see the same behavior as you described/showed in the video. Switch to `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` and the problem should be solved. :)

Comment: interesting, I tested it with my API 31 device and it works fine. but when I switch to API 29 device the problem persists. can u also check it with API 29?

Comment: API 29 emulator working fine, too. Could it be a device bug?

Comment: this is the video of api 29 emulator. the problem is still there [video](https://streamable.com/r4swee). previously i had checked it with physical device. i don't understand why this happens

Comment: thank you for your answer.
1. yes, when i change it back to the 3 button nav, it works fine. but i want it to work with gesture nav. too
2. when i use ```androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView``` searchview doesn't work at all - clicking on it does nothing

Comment: @jane `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` only reacts to clicks on the magnifying class icon. I think it is the intended behavior.